# Как сделать корректное сохранение, счет и суммирование монет в unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делал так, но монеты перезаписываются если перезайти и сыграть еще раз.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AddScore : MonoBehaviour {

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision) {
        Score.coins += 1; //прибавляет одну монету к переменной при прохождении препятствия
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour {

    public Text text;
    public static int coins;

    void Update () {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("coins", coins); //сохраняет монеты
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CoinsText : MonoBehaviour {

    public Text text;
    int coins;

    void Start () {
        coins = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("coins");
        text.text = coins.ToString(); //вывод сохраненных монет
    }
}
```

Comment: нельзя сохранять плеер префс на апдейте. Это медленная и ресурсозатратная операция. Сохраняй один раз перед выходом из игры. И загружай на старте. И проблем никких не будет.

Comment: @Andrew сделал так, все равно перезаписывается                                        
      public class Score : MonoBehaviour {

        public static int coins;
 public GameObject loseBG;


 void Update () {
 
  if (loseBG.activeSelf) {
          PlayerPrefs.SetInt("coins", coins);
          PlayerPrefs.Save();
   
  }
 }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public static int Сoins;

 //загружаем настройки
 void Awake()
 {
     Level = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Сoins", Сoins);
 }

 //сохраняем настройки 
 private void OnApplicationQuit()
 {
     PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Сoins", Сoins);
     PlayerPrefs.Save();
 }
```